# How to get the a create command of a neo4j node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a Node with its relationships in a test environment. I got the node with its relationships in another database. Is it somehow possible to get a `CREATE` statement that inserts the node in the test environment?

Comment: Do you have some unique identifier properties (e.g. `id`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is possible to do this in plain Cypher, but it is quite tricky. I have previously used Cypher to [generate command snippets](https://gist.github.com/szarnyasg/47e53dcd79561e76a3d4af5a9b16965f) in the form of `import-cypher -o [filename] [query]` to export data. This can be adapted to your use case, but there are some design decisions that have to made:

- How do we identify nodes?
- Do relationships have properties?

To get started, let's create an example node:

```
CREATE (:Label1:Label2 {prop1: 'string', prop2: 123, prop3: true})
```

To generate this from the database, use the following command:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH
  reduce(
    acc = '', label IN labels(n) |
    acc + ':`' + label + '`')
    AS labels,
  reduce(
    acc = '', key IN keys(n) |
    acc + '`' + key + '`: ' +
      CASE n[key] = true              WHEN true THEN 'true'  ELSE
      CASE n[key] = false             WHEN true THEN 'false' ELSE
      CASE toInteger(n[key]) = n[key] WHEN true THEN n[key]  ELSE
      CASE toFloat(n[key]) = n[key]   WHEN true THEN n[key]  ELSE
      "'" + n[key] + "'" END END END END
    + ', ') AS properties
WITH
  labels,
  substring(properties, 0, length(properties) - 2) AS properties
RETURN
  'CREATE (' + labels + ' {' + properties + '})'
```

This query results in a `CREATE` command that is essentially the same as the one we have started with:

```
CREATE (:`Label1`:`Label2` {`prop1`: 'string', `prop2`: 123, `prop3`: true})
```

To connect neighbouring nodes, we'll need some ids - I'll improve this answer tomorrow based on the feedback I get.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use seperate sessions or neo4j and try out the process. `Match (n:Label) return n` then extract the properties and put in into an insert query. Now extracting the properties depend on the language.

These were the steps I followed:

1. `query = "MATCH (n) return n"`
2. `result = session1.run(query)`
3. `loop the result object and convert it into dict and get the properties`
4. `then insert them into an insert query`
5. `insert_query = "MERGE/CREATE (n:{properties}) return n"`
6. `session2.run(insert_query)`

This algorithm was implemented in python-neo4j.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe i wrote the question misleading. I got 2 databases and one got the node in it with all relationships. I want this node with all relationships in my second database. I have to do this via cypher, can't use any other programming language. I hope it's clearer now, my bad. Thanks for you answer anyway!

Comment: As Gabor Szarnyas showed the snippet to get the properties, you can insert one's result into other database. It can also be implemented for your answer. That's what we did. We moved our nodes from one neo4j db to other. I've edited my answer. Hope this helps @LaaKii

Comment: @LaaKii 2 does your databases means same neo4j but different Schema?